# Can I go inside Lebanon during a long transit?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, egyptian-citizens, lebanon

I have a flight from Dubai to Cairo with more than 9 hours transit in Lebanon with MEA airlines. Can I go out and discover the country during that time (getting a temporary visa) or should I remain in the airport?

I'm an Egyptian passport holder and a UAE resident.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a visa on arrival at Beirut for Egyptian citizens, you will need:

- **at least $2,000 USD in cash** (not a fee, just proof of funds, but needs to be cash)
- a non-refundable air ticket (round-trip or onward)
- Copy of a hotel reservation for a 3-5 star hotel, **or** name, address, and telephone number of a private citizen in Lebanon

Source: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/LB-Lebanon-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

If you don't have the cash, I'd recommend just staying in the airport. But if you do have the cash, I'd make a refundable reservation at a hotel, or find a Lebanese friend who'd be OK with your listing their information.

Also, I think they'll be fine with other currencies' equivalent of U.S. $2,000, I don't think they're looking specifically for USD.

**Note:** For others who may stumble across this answer, do keep in mind that not every nationality has to bring in cash. Only certain nationalities do, and Egypt is one of them.

Comment: That is a scary large quantity of cash to be carrying around....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas And it can run afoul of currency export regulations in some countries (it doesn't in the OP's case, but if he were, say, traveling from the UK, he'd be subject to a 1,000 GBP limit).

Comment: but your answer is regarding the regular Visit or also in case of transit through Beirut?